# How to form a symbol form two characters in css/html?

Tags: html, css, symbols, diacritics

I want two put two characters together and use it as a single symbol that will be scalable.
I am searching for a general way of doing this.

For example, I want to combine the middle dot and O to get a dot inside the O.
(I know there is a single character for this but this is an example).

> [image]

MWE:

```html
Desired result: &#664; <span style="font-size:200%">&#664;</span>

<div style="padding:20px">
  <span style="letter-spacing:-3px">&#183;O</span>
  <span style="font-size:200%; letter-spacing:-3px">&#183;O</span>
  <br>
  <span style="letter-spacing:-6px">&#183;O</span>
  <span style="font-size:200%; letter-spacing:-6px">&#183;O</span>
  <br>
  <span style="letter-spacing:-9px">&#183;O</span>
  <span style="font-size:200%; letter-spacing:-9px">&#183;O</span>
  <br>
  <span style="letter-spacing:-12px">&#183;O</span>
  <span style="font-size:200%; letter-spacing:-12px">&#183;O</span>
  <br>
  <span style="letter-spacing:-15px">&#183;O</span>
  <span style="font-size:200%; letter-spacing:-15px">&#183;O</span>
  <br>
  <span style="letter-spacing:-18px">&#183;O</span>
  <span style="font-size:200%; letter-spacing:-18px">&#183;O</span>
  <br>
  <span style="letter-spacing:-21px">&#183;O</span>
  <span style="font-size:200%; letter-spacing:-21px">&#183;O</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I position one element below another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40676648/how-can-i-position-one-element-below-another)

Comment: If you're wanting this as a string of characters without a lot of hardcoding, this is going to be nearly impossible, but the first thing you should consider doing is using a fixed width font.  But even if you do find a fixed width font, there's no guarantee it will have all the glyphs you would need.

Answer (score 4):

HTML:

```
<span class="the-char">O</span>
```

CSS:

```
.the-char{
  position: relative;
}

.the-char::after{
  content: ".";
  line-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top:50%;
  transform: translateY(-75%);
  text-align: center;
}

/* change the font size to see result */
.the-char,
.the-char::after{
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

You can change the font-size on the main char and the ::after it will scale proportionally.

**Note:** the dot "." char is not aligned at the center so you will have to make some adjustments with the **top** and **translateY** if you want to center it well inside the main char.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for something like this, it helps,

```css
.dot1{
  font-size:2em;
}
.dot2{
  font-size:1.23em;
}
.dot1::before{
  content:'.';
  position:absolute;
  top:-1px;
  left:35px;
}
.dot2::before{
  content:'.';
  position:absolute;
  top:15px;
  left:13px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="DOT">
    <span class="dot2">O</span>
    <span class="dot1">O</span>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make some divs like below with css below.

css will be

```
.dots {
    float: left;
    width: 12px;
    height: 17px;
    position: relative;
}
span.dot1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 1;
    text-align: center;
    top:-4px;
}
span.dot2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

and html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="dots">
            <span class="dot1">.</span>
            <span class="dot2">O</span>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

```css
 .dots {
    float: left;
    width: 12px;
    height: 17px;
    position: relative;
}
span.dot1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 1;
    text-align: center;
    top: -4px;
}
span.dot2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="dots">
        <span class="dot1">.</span>
        <span class="dot2">O</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```