# How to place elements beneath

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a little website and have two inputs. The problem: One is on the right of the other, but I want to have it beneath. This is a very simple question, though I did not find a good answer.

```html
<form>
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="username">
    <input left="40px" type="text" placeholder="Password" id="password">
    <input type="submit" value="Login now">

</form>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I position one element below another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40676648/how-can-i-position-one-element-below-another)

Comment: Just put them into `<p>` or `<div>` tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make them display as block to have them beneath each other just add

```
input {
    display: block;
}
```

to your css file

```css
input {
    display: block;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="username">
    <input left="40px" type="text" placeholder="Password" id="password">
    <input type="submit" value="Login now">

</form>
```

Comment: now the lower line of the input box and the upper line of the ohter input box are over each other... padding does only change the spache inside the box how can I fix this?

Comment: You can set a margin for your input fields. I have updated my answer

Comment: Thanks! I have the elements in a div now and want to center them, but just the text inside it got centered

Answer (score 1):

Try to add some css class, playing with `flex`:

```
.myForm {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

<form class="myForm">
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="username">
    <input left="40px" type="text" placeholder="Password" id="password">
    <input type="submit" value="Login now">
</form>
```